# Android BottomNavigationView ViewModel setting state programmatically

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-viewmodel

I am trying to move my bottom sheet navigation state to a viewmodel.  This will enable me to set the tab programmatically and also save the tab state on rotation.

In the viewmodel:
enum class NavTab { TAB_1, TAB_2, TAB_3 }

```
val navigationTab: LiveData<NavigationTab> = savedStateHandle.getLiveData("nav_tab")
fun setNavigationTab(tab: NavigationTab) {
    savedStateHandle.set("nav_tab", tab)
}
```

In the activity:

```
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.tab_1:
            viewModel.setNavigationTab(NavTab.TAB_1);
            break;
        case R.id.tab_2:
            viewModel.setNavigationTab(NavTab.TAB_2);
            break;
        case R.id.tab_3:
            viewModel.setNavigationTab(NavTab.TAB_3);
            break;
    }

    return true;
});

viewModel.getNavigationTab().observe(this, this::onNavigationTab);
private void onNavigationTab(NavTab tab) {
    switch (tab) {
        case TAB_1:
            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.tab_1);
            break;
        case TAB_2:
            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.tab_2);
            break;
        case TAB_3:
            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.tab_3);
            break;
    }
}
```

However the problem is when setting the tab programmatically by calling *setNavigationTab* only the fragment is switching the tab is not property selected. I can call

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.tab_2);
```

However if I do this, the view model will see the change and fire the observer, causing an infinite loop.

In the case of programmatically changing the tab I need to switch the fragment and the UI tab.  In case of user clicking the tab, I only need to set the fragment as the tab UI is changed appropriately.

Comment: not sure why you need to observe on navigation tab change, if you want to save the tab selected state, live data will not be cleared if the view model is not destroyed.

Comment: If I want to save the tab that is selected to the viewmodel when when the user selects a new tab, I need to observe tab changes right?

Comment: you already save the selected tab by calling viewModel.setNavigationTab()

Comment: Yup. So that works great when tab is changed by the user. Observe is when is switched programmatically from another fragment.

Comment: Okay, I see your point, one solution could be set the OnItemSelectedListener null before you call bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark tabs as checked without setting the selected item and therefore not calling the selected item listener as follows:

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you may consider doing this:

```
private void onNavigationTab(NavTab tab) {
   bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(null)
   bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(desired_id)
   bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener)
}
```